# How to have different plans in same class

Tags: angular

Currently I have to declare this in 3 components and then send the data according to the plan selected.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  emailMarketingPlan1 = {
    amount: 5.00,
    tax: 1.00,
    type: 'EMAIL_MARKETING',
    text: 0.0
  }

  emailMarketingPlan2 = {
    amount: 10.00,
    tax: 1.00,
    type: 'EMAIL_MARKETING',
    text: 0.0
  }

    emailMarketingPlan3 = {
    amount: 15.00,
    tax: 1.00,
    type: 'EMAIL_MARKETING',
    text: 0.0
  }
```

I was thinking about creating this under shared folder 
  shared/email-marketing-plans.ts

```
export class EmailMarketingPlans {
    amount: 5.00,
    tax: 1.00,
    type: 'EMAIL_MARKETING',
    text: 0.0
}
```

But how can I have multiple plans under the same class EmailMarketingPlans as creating different class for different plans doesn't look like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the class multiple times to set the different plans. I created separate properties for amount, tax, text and type. When the class gets instantiated using `new` keyword you can send the values in it.

```
export class EmailMarketingPlans {
   private amount: int;
   private tax: int;
   private text: any;
   private type: string;

   constructor(amount, tax, type, text) {
     this.amount = amount;
     this.tax = tax;
     this.type = type;
     this.text = text;
   }

   getPlan() {
     return {amount: this.amount, type: this.type, text: this.text, tax: this.tax}
   }
}
```

In your component.ts, you can instantiate EmailMarketingPlans class multiple times with different values.

```
private plan1;
private plan2;
constructor() {
  this.plan1 = new EmailMarketingPlans(5.00, 1.00, 0.00, 'EMAIL_MARKETING');
  this.plan2 = new EmailMarketingPlans(3.00, 3.00, 0.00, 'EMAIL_MARKETING');
  //etc.

  console.log(this.plan1.getPlan());
  console.log(this.plan2.getPlan());
}
```